# Do jade extends/include system means no whole page reload ?

Tags: node.js, templates, pug, page-refresh, partial-page-refresh

is there is any other way than `AJAX/WebSockets` to implement partial-page reloads, in `node.js` applications ?

I was told that template engines with a `block/includes` functionnality like Jade's do that, but when I open up Chrome DevTools on simple apps built with it, it seems it's still a whole page reload.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jade engine compile template file to minified HTML but included blocks still result to a full HTML page, no partial  loading. If you want something more dynamic I guess ajax/ws is best way.

Comment: thank you for your reponse. You say it's the best way but is it the only way ?

Comment: Hmm I guess there are some others but I only use websocket myself. Otherwise you can always have some partial-like loading on client side with  a little bit of jQuery in it.